# Split string into rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I want to split no invoices into rows and store the result in detail transfer status. I tried to use google app script for the first time but there is no result even though the log said it completed.

```
//function for split string invoice number in transfer status sheet
function splitInvoiceNumber() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  //get sheet name
  var sheetTransferStatus = ss.getSheetByName("Status Transfer");
  var sheetDetailTS = ss.getSheetByName("Detail Transfer Status");
  var lastRow = sheetTransferStatus.getLastRow();

  for (var row =2;  row <= lastRow; row ++) {
    var statustransfer = sheetTransferStatus.getRange(row, 4).getValue();
    if (statustransfer === "Delivered") {
      var noPackingList = sheetTransferStatus.getRange(row, 1).getValue();
      var noInvoice = sheetTransferStatus.getRange(row, 2).getValue().split(", ");
      var destination = sheetTransferStatus.getRange(row, 3).getValue();
      Logger.log('Row: ' + row + ' No Packing List: ' + noPackingList);

      //looping for each no packing list
      for (var i = 0; i <= noPackingList.length; i++) {
        sheetDetailTS.appendRow([noPackingList[i], noInvoice, destination, statustransfer])
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you share some values for Status Transfer? I have a hard time guessing the data based on the code alone.
Here are some issues with your code:

- `for (var i = 0; i <= noPackingList.length; i++)`

This is testing the length of the string noPackingList. The loop would for example iterate twice for a value of '9' and 12 times for 'Hello World'. Based on what I can gather from your code I don't think you intent to appending the row as many times as there are characters in your noPackingList string.

- noInvoice

If one of the returned values isn't a string (for example an empty cell) your code will crash as split cannot be performed on null.

I would replace by the following:

```
       var noInvoice = sheetTransferStatus.getRange(row, 2).getValue()
  var noInvoiceSplit = []
  if (typeof noInvoice === "string") {noInvoiceSplit = noInvoice.split(", ");}
```

Edit: By looking at your data, I'm guessing that you want to split values in the invoice numbers so that each value gets printed on its own row as long as the Status Delivery shows delivered. This code will achieve that. Not sure if this is what you were going for but this is a starting point:

```
    //function for split string invoice number in transfer status sheet
function splitInvoiceNumber() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  //get sheet name
  var sheetTransferStatus = ss.getSheetByName("Status Transfer");
  var sheetDetailTS = ss.getSheetByName("Detail Transfer Status");
  var lastRow = sheetTransferStatus.getLastRow();

  for (var row =2;  row <= lastRow; row ++) {
    var statustransfer = sheetTransferStatus.getRange(row, 4).getValue();
    if (statustransfer === "Delivered") {
      var noPackingList = sheetTransferStatus.getRange(row, 1).getValue();
      var noInvoice = sheetTransferStatus.getRange(row, 2).getValue()
      var noInvoiceSplit = []
      if (typeof noInvoice === "string") {noInvoiceSplit = noInvoice.split(", ");}
      var destination = sheetTransferStatus.getRange(row, 3).getValue();
      Logger.log('Row: ' + row + ' No Packing List: ' + noPackingList);

      //looping for each invoice split
      for (var i = 0; i < noInvoiceSplit.length; i++) {
        sheetDetailTS.appendRow([noInvoiceSplit[i], noInvoice, destination, statustransfer])
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi, this is a link of google sheet that consist data of transfer status
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mf6exOQi56z3wCPyenkATINeTHPpIucKjUon12DEbe0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks. I changed the code to address both the issues I raised. Please check whether the above code gives you the results you are looking for. I deleted the loop because I don't think you intended to explode every character of every row of noPackingList which is what your code used to do.